# Output line of code while executing it in Python

Tags: python, programming-languages, interpreted-language

I am developing a small program which I want to give to my younger friends to introduce them to the bare minimum basics of programming using Python.
In it, I want to add functionality to output the line of code that is being executed, as it is being executed, to the console (or as a variable within Python that can be printed using suitable commands).
I want this so that users of this program may learn better by understanding the underlying process that is going on real time, at the higher level (programming language execution).
I thought this would be possible especially because Python is an interpreter language, so the code is playing part until the penultimate step of executing it.

Is there any way to do this intrinsically? If not, I think there should be a way to write a program that will​ take another program as input and execute while also having access to source code. With some advanced parsing, that kind of design will be able to achieve this, but I'm looking for preferably a more natural way to do this.

Comment: Why not just use e.g. http://pythontutor.com/?

Comment: This is to be done in a school-like environment, and real-time internet access is not a guarantee, unfortunately. (Not even for me).

Comment: Well it's open source, so you can host it locally or see how it does what it does, but how to reimplement something like it is far too broad a question for SO.

Comment: Hmm.. thanks for the comment. I'll check it out.

Comment: [pdb — The Python Debugger](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) can do pretty much all of that -- step through code, print what line of code is next to be executed, display the result of executed code, etc - a great analytics tool.

Comment: agree with @downshift; putting import pdb; pdb.set_trace() at the top of your program will let you step through each line [it will get a little odd if you use list comprehensions but not horribly so if you keep the size small].  (Hit n to run the next command)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be perfect to teach using but surely exec would work?
As in:

```
mycommand = "a = 5**3"
print(mycommand)
exec(mycommand)
print("a = "+str(a))
```

Comment: That's what I meant by the second part of my question. This will definitely work, but it will get complicated for `for` loops, nested operations, etc.

Comment: No, no natural way to do it, python is too difficult to parse without a lot of complex logic that would just waste time when code can be viewed on almost all modern systems as its being run.

Answer (score 0):

A nice tool, that also works offline is the thonny (debugging) editor. Start the action "Debug Current Script" and then let the students "Step Over" each line of code as it is highlighted. Values of output variable will appear in a right hand tab, while the output of all print statements would appear over the "Shell" window.
 [thonny editor in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a6UW.png)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35702465)